# Jquery ajax FormData() posting incorrect key names

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, form-data

Here's my ajax code which I am using to post form data with FormData object. Here I am trying to post form data with image upload to controller.

```
       var data1= new FormData(); 
       data1.append("doc_photo", $('#file-doc-photo')[0].files[0]);
       data1.append("name", $('#txt-doc-name').val());
       data1.append("email", $('#txt-doc-emailid').val());
       data1.append("phone", $('#txt-doc-phno').val());
       data1.append("country ", $('#ddl-doc-country').val());

        $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: baseUrl + "doctor/ctr_doctor/update_doctor",
                       data: data1,
                       cache: false,
                       dataType: "json",
                       contentType: false,
                       processData: false,
                       success: function (res)
                      {
                         alert("Hello");
                      }
          });
```

Console Output:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryoLvd2A1IOU3cxAPp
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name Disallowed Key Characters.
```

I have modified Codeigniters core Input class to find out the error.

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
    {

        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
        {
            //$str will append post var key in error message
            exit($str.' Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
        {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

I have enabled XSS filter in config.

I know it's posting form key incorrectly but why that is what I want to know.

Comment: write print_r above if condition in controller

Comment: what is inside `$('#txt-doc-name').val()` ?

Comment: It will fetch the value of the textfield using its id

Comment: i know what it will do, i'm asking what is inside value, because it have `Disallowed Key Characters.`

Comment: Simply a name is there inside $('#txt-doc-name').val() without any of the special characters.  For example i will enter the name Shalaka in the textfield.